# Двоичное дерево поиска. Почему вывод не упорядочен от меньшего к большему?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Вывод двоичного дерева поиска всегда упорядочен от наименьшего к большему. То есть если дерево растянуть в прямую линию, слева будет наименьшее значение, справа наибольшее значение. Уже сломал голову чтобы вывод у данного кода был верен. Сейчас он в корень ставит максимальное и вперед по убывающей.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct BinTree{
    int value;
    BinTree* left;
    BinTree* right;
};
void newBinTree(int val, BinTree** Tree) { // пам1 знач, пам2 указ на указ
    if ((*Tree) == NULL){ // пам2 нулл? ...
        (*Tree) = new BinTree;
        (*Tree)->value = val;
        (*Tree)->left = (*Tree)->right = NULL; // полям left и right присвоить null
        return;
    }
    if (val > (*Tree)-> value){ // если переданное больше предыдущего
        newBinTree(val, &(*Tree)->right); // поместить его в право, передается параметр, и второй параметр ссылка на добавляемый и в право
    } else {
        newBinTree(val, &(*Tree) -> left); // иначе в левый
    }
}

void Print(BinTree**Tree, int l){ // печать дерева , первый пам это узел, второй пам ?
    int i; // ???
    if (*Tree != NULL) { // если узер не null
        Print(&((**Tree).right), l + 1); // вызываем функцию принт, передаем ей узел справа, второй пам ?
        for (i = 1; i <= l; i++){ // ???
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << (**Tree).value << endl; // вывод значения дерева
        Print(&((**Tree).left), l + 1);// вывод левого
    }
}

int main() {
     BinTree* Tree = NULL; // создаем указатель на структуру и присваиваем ему null (ноль) по умолчанию, в tree хранится адрес указателя
     vector<int> result;
     vector<int> numbers = {8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13};
     for(auto k : numbers) {
        newBinTree(k, &Tree); // после первой итерации tree будет уже объект корень
        }
     Print(&Tree, 0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: кто вам сказал что "вывод двоичного дерева поиска всегда упорядочен от наибольшего к наименьшему" ?? Что это за бред. Почитайте про различные [способы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) обхода деревьев

Comment: @ampawd https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Двоичное_дерево_поиска читайте условия, а так же посмотрите на картинку справа (картинку с деревом и растяните дерево мысленно в прямую)

Comment: Вывод дерева содержит в себе также его обход, который осуществляется несколькими способами, один из которых обходит в отсортированном порядке (тоесть например от наименьшего к наибольшему), у остальных порядок абсолютно другой, поэтому ваше утверждение что "вывод дерева всегда упорядочен" является неверным

Comment: по ссылке что я вам предоставил обратите внимание на центрированный обход, этот обход как раз осуществляется в отсортировнном порядке (как раз то, что вам нужно)   [центрированный обход](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_(LNR))

Comment: @ampawd ну если двоичное дерево поиска само по себе упорядоченно, то как его вывод может быть не упорядоченным ? За ссылку спасибо.

Comment: вы наверное путаете упорядоченность списка с упорядоченностью дерева - это разные вещи

Comment: @ampawd http://rsdn.org/article/alg/binstree.xml не путаю, но похоже Вы правы в той части, что все зависит от обхода дерева. Только опять же непонятно, дерево же упорядоченно, почему у него три разных способа обхода, которые делают его не упорядоченным в выводе.

Comment: Есть вершина и два потомка, под упорядоченностью понимается, что значение в левом потомке меньше значения вершины, а значение в правом потомке больше или равно значению вершины. В вашей программе если вы хотите получить вывод по возрастанию, то нужно поменять местами left и right в функции print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, у вас что то не так с ньюансами C++, так как я реализовал то же самое на C# и оно работает. Вот пример

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public TreeNode Left;
    public TreeNode Right;
    public int V;
}

TreeNode BuildTree(TreeNode root, int v)
{
    if (root == null) return new TreeNode() {V = v};
    if(root.V < v) root.Right = BuildTree(root.Right, v);
    else root.Left = BuildTree(root.Left, v);
    return root;
}

void Print(TreeNode root, int level = 0)
{
    if (root == null) return;
    Print(root.Right, level+1);
    Console.WriteLine($"{new String('\t', level)}{root.V}");    
    Print(root.Left, level+1);
}
```

Запускаю вот так

```
void Main()
{
    TreeNode root = null;
    var data = new[] {8, 3, 10, 1, 6, 14, 4, 7, 13};
    foreach(var v in data)
        root = BuildTree(root, v);          
    Print(root);
}
```

Вывод

```
    14
      13
  10
8
      7
    6
      4
  3
    1
```

**UPD**

для [InOrder](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/) обхода, надо сначала левый узел пройти, потом текущий, потом правый.

Само дерево выглядит так:

[image: ...]

Код InOrder обхода

```
void Print(TreeNode root, int level = 0)
{
    if (root == null) return;
    Print(root.Left, level+1);
    Console.WriteLine($"{new String('\t', level)}{root.V}");    
    Print(root.Right, level+1);
}
```

Вывод

```
    1
  3
      4
    6
      7
8
  10
      13
    14
```

Comment: Так у меня то же работает и вывод такой же.

Comment: @Aleksey тогда я не понял в чем вопрос? Этот вывод именно то, что должно быть

Comment: @Aleksey а, я понял. Вам нужен InOrder обход, где сначала левый узел, потом текущий, потом правый. Сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: нужеy InOrder-Tree-Walk, у Вас результат в выводе точно не от такого подхода.

Comment: @Aleksey я же обновил ответ, в обнове именно inOrder обход, можете проверить, загуглить или пройти просто по ссылке из ответа

Comment: может я чего то непонимаю ? В моём понимании InOrder строится на понятии что для любого узла x, ключи в левом поддереве не превышают x.key. В правом поддереве не превышают x.key. Inorder позволяет вывести ключи в отсортированном виде. Может я неверно понимаю Ваш вывод, а заодно и свой ? Как вы думаю ваш вывод соответствует условию что я описал ?

Comment: @Aleksey Смотрите, есть бинарное дерево. Свойство бинарного дерева - что у каждого узла максимум 2 подузла - левый и правый. Есть бинарное дерево поиска - это бинарное дерево, у которого для каждого узла слева только меньшие или равные узлы, справа только бОльшие. Заметьте, я пока ничего не говорил про InOrder, я говорил только о самом дереве поиска.

Comment: @Aleksey так вот, допустим, у нас есть бинарное поиска. Оно состоит из узлов. Когда мы будем обходить это дерево, мы можем это сделать по разному. Можем начать с самого левого узла, можеи начать с самого правого, можем начать с центрального - это есть гулять по узлам дерева  можно по разному

Comment: @Aleksey InOrder - это просто один из способов прогулки по дереву. Причем по бинарному, не обязательно по дереву поиска. То есть даже если у вас есть просто бинарное дерево, не важно какие там значения в узлах, мы всё равно можем гулять по этому дереву в InOrder порядке

Comment: @Aleksey таким образом, обходу InOrder вообще без разницы, по какому дереву ходить, поиска или не поиска, главное, чтобы оно было бинарное, то есть максимум 2 подузла в каждом узле

Comment: @Aleksey а вот уже для бинарного дерева поиска, так как слева у него меньшие узлы, а справа большие, то означает что при InOrder обходе, где сначала обходятся левые, потом текущий, потом правый, то при таком проходе сначала будут посещены меньшие узлы, потом большие, то есть вывод при посещении будет сортирован от меньшего к большему, что мы и видим в ответе а апдейте.

Comment: а я себе ваш и свой вывод по наставлению преподавателя представлял вот как: вот у Вас в выводе единица это корень получился, узел нулевого уровня, у единицы два поддерева, 3 и 4. 3 бездетна, у 4 одно поддерево 6, у 6 семерка и т.д.

Comment: @Aleksey нет. Именно в случае вашего примера и моего ответа, корень дерева 8. Само дерево, что мы построили выглядит [так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjpj.png), обратите внимание, что это и есть бинарное дерево поиска. Во время InOrder обхода, мы его обходим слева направо.

Comment: и как тогда в выводе увидеть что значение левого потомка меньше родителя, а значение правого потомка больше родителя ?

Comment: @Aleksey я вам выше дал картинку. Если вы поглядите на картинку и вывод в ответе, вы поймете.